# How is json data posted?

Tags: python, json, http, flask

My `flask` code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/sheets/api',methods=["POST"])
def insert():
    if request.get_json():
        return "<h1>Works! </h1>"
    else:
        return "<h1>Does not work.</h1>"
```

When the request is:

```
POST /sheets/api HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10080
Cache-Control: no-cache

{'key':'value'}
```

The result is `<h1>Does not work.</h1>`.

When I added a `Content-Type` header:

```
POST /sheets/api HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{'key':'value'}
```

I get a 400 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not posting valid JSON. JSON strings use *double* quotes:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

With single quotes the string is not valid JSON and a *400 Bad Request* response is returned.

Demo against a local Flask server implementing only your route:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:5000/sheets/api', data="{'key':'value'}", headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}).text
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n'
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:5000/sheets/api', data='{"key":"value"}', headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}).text
'<h1>Works! </h1>'
```